# Kubernetes: Is it possible to get master nodes IP/Name in GKE regional cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

As per the google GKE documentation, for regional cluster's masters and nodes are spread across multiple zones. Is there anyway in GKE to see the master nodes with which zone it is running?

I also tried kubectl cluster-info and it gives me the below result. Is that mean my cluster have only one master running ?

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://xx.xx.xx.xx
GLBCDefaultBackend is running at https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/default-http-backend:http/proxy
Heapster is running at https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy
```

Comment: Output for kubectl v1.23 has apparently changed: `Kubernetes master` has been replaced by `Kubernetes control plane`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master nodes in GKE are managed by google, thus you will not be able to see them.

By default, a regional GKE cluster will create three master nodes spread across three zones.

Therefore, only a single static API endpoint is provided for the entire cluster.

The https://xx.xx.xx.xx represents your cluster API endpoint.

I invite you to visit this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture) to have an insight on how GKE operates.

Answer (score 0):

In GKE you don't have a master per say.

GKE and EKS takes care of master node for you, this is mostly the adventage of those features instead of using AWS and GCP to just spawn a VM.